# Parallel transport of quadratic form

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

By the concept of parallel transport, we can transport a vector by Levi-Civita connection over the Riemannian manifold. It allows us to have an isomorphism between tangent spaces along a geodesic and the orthogonal basis transfer along the geodesic.

If we have a quadratic form by a symmetry matrix with some negative and positive eigenvalues,
can we transform it via parallel transport along a curve, is not necessarily geodesic? If yes would you please refer me to a suitable reference?

Perhaps it is possible to consider some particular manifolds or connections. But I am not sure if it is possible or not.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: A quadratic form is a tensor, and the notion of being parallel along a curve is defined for all tensors, so the short answer is: yes

Comment: Thanks, Harish.  Yes, you are right. Would you please let me know a reference that exactly proves the statement? It is in my mind if the curve has singularity I mean the derivative is zero how can transfer the quadratic form along the curve? It seems to me we can do it locally but globally I am not sure. I am so thankful if you introduce some references.

Comment: I want to know if the defined form on the tangent space is invariant along a curve or not.

Comment: Any Riemannian geometry book does this (see Jack Lee's *Introduction to Riemannian manifolds* or Gallot-Hullin-Lafontaine's *Riemannian geometry*). On a **non-sigular** curve $\gamma$  (*i.e* $\gamma' \neq 0$ everywhere along the curve) there is a unique operation (denoted $\nabla_{\gamma'}$, $D_t$, $\nabla/dt$ or even $D/dt$) called the covariant derivative along $\gamma$ that extends the covariant derivative to tensors defined along the curve. By the way, I'm not Harish!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Didier! Sorry for mistake :)